# Insert delete, dynamoDb and check SpringBoot

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am trying insert in dynamoDb but I first remove duplicate data and then I insert. I don't use key Primary partition key from dynamoDb because, the items have key logic.

Then... I "insert" in

```
     try {
         repository.delete(list);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

     try {
         repository.save(list);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have 2 problems:

1º-- I don't come catch, but I don't have insert in Bd.

2º I lost All register because I first delete.

3º How Can I do :

boolean result;

```
    try {
        result = repository.save(list);
```

Sorry for my English.